# Table inside a table not taking full width of the parent table

Tags: html, css

I have a table nested in a table. I have specified widths for both using CSS. But the nested table gets cut and doesnt take the whole width of the parent table.

Images to show this:

Peview of the page with the nested table hidden

[image: Preview of Page with the nested table hidden]

Preview of the page with the nested table showing:

[image: Preview of the Page with the nested table showing]

**Edit**
This is what happens when i remove the fixed width from the nested table audition-box.

[image]

MY HTML:

```
<div class="audition-category">
                    <table class="fixed actb1">
                        <tr class="tr-darkBlue auditionc-tr2">
                            <th class="acol1">Audition Times by Status</th>
                            <th class="acol2">#</th>
                            <th class="acol3">Send Notifiations?</th>
                            <th class="acol4"></th>
                        </tr>
                        <tr class="tr-cyan c1">
                            <td class="ccol1">New Audition Timess</td>
                            <td class="ccol2">12</td>
                            <td class="ccol2b"><input type="checkbox" name="" value="" /></td>
                            <td class="ccol3">
                                <ul class="expand-actions" id="expand">
                                    <li class="expand es-btn1 show"><a> <img src="img/plus.png" alt="" /></a></li>
                                    <li class="collapse es-btn1"><a> <img src="img/minus.png" alt="" /></a></li>
                                </ul>

                            </td>
                        </tr>

                        <tr class="ad22">
                            <td class="aud-parent">
                            <table class="tr-hidden audition-box audition-box1 fixed">
                                <tr>
                                    <th class="ab-c3">Audition Time</th>
                                    <th class="ab-c1">Name</th>
                                    <th class="ab-c2">Role</th>
                                    <th class="ab-c4">Agency</th>

                                </tr>
                                <tr class="tr-graybg">
                                    <td class="ab-c3">10:00 AM</td>
                                    <td class="ab-c1">Alice Wetterlund</td>
                                    <td class="ab-c2">Quiet Landing Flight Attendant</td>
                                    <td class="ab-c4">CESD</td>

                                </tr>
                                <tr>
                                    <td class="ab-c3">10:55 AM</td>
                                    <td class="ab-c1">Linara Washington</td>
                                    <td class="ab-c2">Quiet Landing Flight Attendant</td>
                                    <td class="ab-c4">Abrams Artists (Commercial Adult) - LA</td>

                                </tr>
                                <tr class="tr-graybg">
                                    <td class="ab-c3">11:15 AM</td>
                                    <td class="ab-c1">Felice Heather Monteith</td>
                                    <td class="ab-c2">Quiet Landing Flight Attendant</td>
                                    <td class="ab-c4">Adele's Kids & Adults Talent Management</td>
                                </tr>
                                <tr>
                                    <td class="ab-c3">11:40 AM</td>
                                    <td class="ab-c1">Kelly Ewing</td>
                                    <td class="ab-c2">Quiet Landing Flight Attendant</td>
                                    <td class="ab-c4">Applegate Agency Models and Talent - Hollywood, FL</td>
                                </tr>
                                <tr class="tr-graybg">
                                    <td class="ab-c3">1:15 PM</td>
                                    <td class="ab-c1">Dana Powell</td>
                                    <td class="ab-c2">Quiet Landing Flight Attendant</td>
                                    <td class="ab-c4">Conan Carroll and Associates Commercial and Print</td>
                                </tr>
                                <tr>
                                    <td class="ab-c3">1:55 PM</td>
                                    <td class="ab-c1">FUSCHIA! FUSCHIA!</td>
                                    <td class="ab-c2">Quiet Landing Flight Attendant</td>
                                    <td class="ab-c4">Abrams Artsts (Commercial Adult) - LA</td>
                                </tr>
                                <tr class="tr-graybg">
                                    <td class="ab-c3">2:30 PM</td>
                                    <td class="ab-c1">Jill Benjamin</td>
                                    <td class="ab-c2">Quiet Landing Flight Attendant</td>
                                    <td class="ab-c4">CESD</td>
                                </tr>
                                <tr>
                                    <td class="ab-c3">2:50 PM</td>
                                    <td class="ab-c1">elizabeth keener</td>
                                    <td class="ab-c2">Quiet Landing Flight Attendant</td>
                                    <td class="ab-c4">DPN Talent</td>
                                </tr>
                                <tr class="tr-graybg">
                                    <td class="ab-c3">3:10 PM</td>
                                    <td class="ab-c1">michelle carmichael</td>
                                    <td class="ab-c2">Quiet Landing Flight Attendant</td>
                                    <td class="ab-c4">Face2Face Entertainment Model & Talent Management</td>
                                </tr>
                                <tr>
                                    <td class="ab-c3">3:55 PM</td>
                                    <td class="ab-c1">Liz Bolton</td>
                                    <td class="ab-c2">Quiet Landing Flight Attendant</td>
                                    <td class="ab-c4">Conan Carroll and Associates Commercial and Print</td>
                                </tr>
                                <tr class="tr-graybg">
                                    <td class="ab-c3">4:05 PM</td>
                                    <td class="ab-c1">Shari Washington</td>
                                    <td class="ab-c2">Quiet Landing Flight Attendant</td>
                                    <td class="ab-c4">Abrams Artists (Commercial Adult) - LA</td>
                                </tr>
                                <tr>
                                    <td class="ab-c3">6:50 PM</td>
                                    <td class="ab-c1">Christie Lynn</td>
                                    <td class="ab-c2">Quiet Landing Flight Attendant</td>
                                    <td class="ab-c4">Ford - Los Angeles</td>
                                </tr>
                            </table>
                            </td>
                        </tr>

                        <tr>
                            <td class="ccol1">Changed Audition Times</td>
                            <td class="ccol2">3</td>
                            <td class="ccol2b"><input type="checkbox" name="" value="" /></td>
                            <td class="ccol3">
                                <ul class="expand-actions ea2" id="expand">
                                    <li class="expand es-btn2 show"><a> <img src="img/plus.png" alt="" /></a></li>
                                    <li class="collapse es-btn2"><a> <img src="img/minus.png" alt="" /></a></li>
                                </ul>

                            </td>
                        </tr>

                        <tr class="ad22">
                            <td class="aud-parent">
                            <table class="tr-hidden audition-box audition-box2 fixed">
                                                                <tr>
                                    <th class="ab-c3">Audition Time</th>
                                    <th class="ab-c1">Name</th>
                                    <th class="ab-c2">Role</th>
                                    <th class="ab-c4">Agency</th>

                                </tr>
                                <tr class="tr-graybg">
                                    <td class="ab-c3">10:00 AM</td>
                                    <td class="ab-c1">Alice Wetterlund</td>
                                    <td class="ab-c2">Quiet Landing Flight Attendant</td>
                                    <td class="ab-c4">CESD</td>

                                </tr>
                                <tr>
                                    <td class="ab-c3">10:55 AM</td>
                                    <td class="ab-c1">Linara Washington</td>
                                    <td class="ab-c2">Quiet Landing Flight Attendant</td>
                                    <td class="ab-c4">Abrams Artists (Commercial Adult) - LA</td>

                                </tr>
                                <tr class="tr-graybg">
                                    <td class="ab-c3">11:15 AM</td>
                                    <td class="ab-c1">Felice Heather Monteith</td>
                                    <td class="ab-c2">Quiet Landing Flight Attendant</td>
                                    <td class="ab-c4">Adele's Kids & Adults Talent Management</td>
                                </tr>


                            </table>
                            </td>
                        </tr>

                        <tr class="tr-cyan auditionc-tr2">
                            <td class="ccol1">Cancelled Audition Times</td>
                            <td class="ccol2">8</td>
                            <td class="ccol2b"><input type="checkbox" name="" value="" /></td>
                            <td class="ccol3">
                                <ul class="expand-actions" id="expand">
                                    <li class="expand es-btn3 show"><a> <img src="img/plus.png" alt="" /></a></li>
                                    <li class="collapse es-btn3"><a> <img src="img/minus.png" alt="" /></a></li>
                                </ul>

                            </td>
                        </tr>

                        <tr>
                            <td class="aud-parent">
                            <table class="tr-hidden audition-box audition-box3 fixed">

                                                                <tr>
                                    <th class="ab-c3">Audition Time</th>
                                    <th class="ab-c1">Name</th>
                                    <th class="ab-c2">Role</th>
                                    <th class="ab-c4">Agency</th>

                                </tr>
                                <tr class="tr-graybg">
                                    <td class="ab-c3">10:00 AM</td>
                                    <td class="ab-c1">Alice Wetterlund</td>
                                    <td class="ab-c2">Quiet Landing Flight Attendant</td>
                                    <td class="ab-c4">CESD</td>

                                </tr>
                                <tr>
                                    <td class="ab-c3">10:55 AM</td>
                                    <td class="ab-c1">Linara Washington</td>
                                    <td class="ab-c2">Quiet Landing Flight Attendant</td>
                                    <td class="ab-c4">Abrams Artists (Commercial Adult) - LA</td>

                                </tr>
                                <tr class="tr-graybg">
                                    <td class="ab-c3">11:15 AM</td>
                                    <td class="ab-c1">Felice Heather Monteith</td>
                                    <td class="ab-c2">Quiet Landing Flight Attendant</td>
                                    <td class="ab-c4">Adele's Kids & Adults Talent Management</td>
                                </tr>
                                <tr>
                                    <td class="ab-c3">11:40 AM</td>
                                    <td class="ab-c1">Kelly Ewing</td>
                                    <td class="ab-c2">Quiet Landing Flight Attendant</td>
                                    <td class="ab-c4">Applegate Agency Models and Talent - Hollywood, FL</td>
                                </tr>
                                <tr class="tr-graybg">
                                    <td class="ab-c3">1:15 PM</td>
                                    <td class="ab-c1">Dana Powell</td>
                                    <td class="ab-c2">Quiet Landing Flight Attendant</td>
                                    <td class="ab-c4">Conan Carroll and Associates Commercial and Print</td>
                                </tr>
                                <tr>
                                    <td class="ab-c3">1:55 PM</td>
                                    <td class="ab-c1">FUSCHIA! FUSCHIA!</td>
                                    <td class="ab-c2">Quiet Landing Flight Attendant</td>
                                    <td class="ab-c4">Abrams Artsts (Commercial Adult) - LA</td>
                                </tr>
                                <tr class="tr-graybg">
                                    <td class="ab-c3">2:30 PM</td>
                                    <td class="ab-c1">Jill Benjamin</td>
                                    <td class="ab-c2">Quiet Landing Flight Attendant</td>
                                    <td class="ab-c4">CESD</td>
                                </tr>
                                <tr>
                                    <td class="ab-c3">2:50 PM</td>
                                    <td class="ab-c1">elizabeth keener</td>
                                    <td class="ab-c2">Quiet Landing Flight Attendant</td>
                                    <td class="ab-c4">DPN Talent</td>
                                </tr>



                            </table>
                            </td>
                        </tr>

                        <tr>
                            <td>
                            sddasdasda
                            </td>
                        </tr>

                    </table>                    
                </div>
```

The CSS for the table styles:

```
    .audition-category {
        width: 96%;
        margin: auto;
        border: 5px solid #4a81b6;
        -webkit-border-radius: 6px;
        border-radius: 6px;
        margin-top: 12px;
    }
        .audition-category table {

        }
        .audition-category table tr {
            height: 10px;
            height: 34px;
        }
        .auditionc-tr2 {
            height: 34px!important;
        }

        .ad22 {height: 1px!important;  }

        .audition-category table th{
            text-align: left;
            padding-left: 10px;
            font-family: 'PT Sans', sans-serif;
            font-size: 21px;
            color: #FFF;
            font-weight: normal;
            line-height: 1;
            margin-top: -5px;

            font-size: 18px;
        }
        .audition-category table td {
            text-align: left;
            padding-left: 10px;
            font-family: 'PT Sans', sans-serif;
            font-size: 14px;
            color :#333;
        }
        .aud-c1 {width: 180px;}
        .aud-c2 {width: 580px;}

        .audition-category .ccol1 {word-wrap:break-word; max-width: 1px;}
        .audition-category .ccol2 {position: relative;  display: inline-block; min-width: 60px;}
        .audition-category .ccol2b {}

.aud-parent {
    margin: 0!important;
    padding: 0!important;
    width: 100%!important;
    padding-bottom: 0px!important;
    padding-left: 1px!important;

}   

.audition-box {
    display: none;
    margin-bottom: 5px;
    width: 847px;
}
    .audition-box tr {
        height: 25px!important;
    }
    .audition-box th {
        color: #333!important;
        font-size: 14px!important;
        font-weight: bold!important;
    }
    .audition-box td {

    }   

    .ab-c1 {width: 150px;font-size: 13px!important;}
    .ab-c2 {width: 200px;font-size: 13px!important;}
    .ab-c3 {width: 100px;font-size: 13px!important;}
    .ab-c4 {width: 300px; font-size: 13px!important; margin: 0!important; padding: 0!important}


table.fixed { table-layout:fixed!important; }
table.fixed td { overflow: hidden!important; word-break: break-all; }


.acol1{min-width: 100px;font-size: 17px!important;}
.acol2{min-width: 180px;}
.acol3{min-width: 300px; font-size: 16px!important; }
.acol4{}

.audition-category .actb1 {/*width: 100%; overflow: auto;*/ min-width: 830px; max-width: 849px;}
/*.bbig {max-width: 300px;}*/
.hide {display: none!important;}

.tr-graybg {background: #eee;}

.show {display: block!important;}
```

Comment: You have a fixed width set for your nested `.audition-box` tables. Please limit the use of `!important` to, "almost never."

Comment: I have edited to add a preview when .audition-box table's fixed width is removed. Now it doesnt expand to the full width of the parent. As for using important, i plan on removing them one by one as soon as this issue is solved.

Answer (score 1):

You're putting the nested table within the first column of the table. The rest of the rows are getting pushed to the right when it has a fixed width, as it extends the width of that entire column.

EDIT: To fix it, the simplest solution would probably be to, instead of having the tables nested, have them be separate but wrapped inside a single div for formatting.

Comment: Adding colspan="3" to the td holding the nested table worked. Thanks your answer helped

Answer (score 1):

Nested table in inside id <td> so you have to set width 100% to those <td> as well as set colspan=4 in those <td>,then on only then it's works.

```
<td style="width:100%;" colspan="4">
  <table style="width:100%;">
  ...
  ...
  ...
</table>
</td>
```

I hope this will help you

Answer (score 0):

For the inner table tag, adding `style="width: 100%"` worked for me.

```
<table style="width: 100%;">
```